# How to automatically install Bioconductor package on which a CRAN package depends through a long chain of dependencies?

Tags: r, bioconductor, cran

I have a package `metagam` which is on CRAN, and it passes all of [CRAN's automated tests](https://cran.rstudio.com//web/checks/check_results_metagam.html). However, the package depends on the Bioconductor package `multtest` through the chain of dependencies `metagam` <- `metap` <- `mutoss` <- `multtest`. This is visualized below for the dependencies of the `metap` package.

```r
# Code for creating dependency graph
library(miniCRAN)
plot(makeDepGraph("metap", suggests = FALSE))
```

[image: Dependencies of the metap package, on which metagam depends.]

The answer to [this question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/3365/r-package-development-how-does-one-automatically-install-bioconductor-packages) suggests adding `biocViews:` to `DEPENDENCIES`. Accordingly, the relevant parts of my `DESCRIPTION` look like this:

```
biocViews: 
Imports: 
    dplyr,
    furrr,
    ggplot2,
    knitr,
    metafor,
    metap,
    purrr,
    rlang,
    stringr,
    tidyr
RoxygenNote: 7.1.0
Suggests: 
    future,
    mgcv,
    gamm4,
    gratia,
    roxygen2,
    rmarkdown,
    devtools,
    covr,
    viridis,
    testthat (>= 2.1.0)
```

However, adding `biocViews` appears to only work for first-order dependencies. In my case, there are no Bioconductor packages listed in `DESCRIPTION`, and hence automatic package installation fails. This is shown by the example below.

```r
# Remove packages 'metap', 'mutoss', and 'multtest' if they are installed
# If, any of these are installed, the dependency 'multtest' will not be attempted to be installed
pkgs <- installed.packages()[, "Package", drop = TRUE]
if("metap" %in% pkgs) remove.packages("metap")
#> Removing package from '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library'
#> (as 'lib' is unspecified)
if("mutoss" %in% pkgs) remove.packages("mutoss")
#> Removing package from '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library'
#> (as 'lib' is unspecified)
if("multtest" %in% pkgs) remove.packages("multtest")

# Install 'metagam', which trigges installation of the dependency 'metap'
# The dependencies are 'metagam' <- 'metap' <- 'mutoss' <- 'multtest'
install.packages("metagam")
#> Warning: dependency 'multtest' is not available
#> also installing the dependencies 'mutoss', 'metap'
#> 
#> The downloaded binary packages are in
#>  /var/folders/sz/q9lc1ggd66n5k5x_yp094hgh0000gn/T//Rtmphvg646/downloaded_packages
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Furthermore, this causes the package to fail, because the dependency on `multtest` is real:

```r
# The code below is from the examples of the metagam::metagam() function
# The last line fails because the dependency 'multtest' is not available
library(metagam)
library(mgcv)
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> This is mgcv 1.8-31. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.

## Create 5 datasets
set.seed(1234)
datasets <- lapply(1:5, function(x) gamSim(scale = 5, verbose = FALSE))

## Fit a GAM in each dataset, then use strip_rawdata() to remove
## individual participant data
models <- lapply(datasets, function(dat){
  ## This uses the gam() function from mgcv
  model <- gam(y ~ s(x0, bs = "cr") + s(x1, bs = "cr") + s(x2, bs = "cr"), data = dat)
  ## This uses strip_rawdata() from metagam
  strip_rawdata(model)
})

## Next, we meta-analyze the models.
## It is often most convenient to analyze a single term at a time. We focus on s(x1).
meta_analysis <- metagam(models, terms = "s(x1)", grid_size = 30)
#> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called 'multtest'
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I know I can inform the users, either on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Lifebrain/metagam) or via a startup message, that they need to run the following lines before attempting to install `metagam`, but it does not provide the best user experience.

```r
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager") 
BiocManager::install("multtest")
```

What seems to me as the solution, is adding `multtest` to Imports. However, wouldn't this give a warning about unused imports, since no functions from `multtest` is directly used by `metagam`, but rather through the chain of dependencies specified above. I could not create such a warning on my own system, running `R CMD check --as-cran`, so maybe CRAN is fine with this? Alternatively, I could add a line of code somewhere using `multtest`, but this seems very hacky.

To summarize, my question is what I should do for the `multtest` package to be automatically installed when `metagam` is installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Bioconductor has twice-yearly releases, and this differs from CRAN release practices, the 'right' thing to do is to use Bioconductor tools to install your package, so `BiocManager::install("metap")`. It does not matter that metap is a CRAN package. BiocManager installs the correct version of the Bioconductor package for the user's version of R.

If this solution isn't palatable, then the next-best right thing to do is to adjust your dependencies to avoid direct or indirect dependencies on Bioconductor packages.

Comment: The trick I mentioned about using "biocViews:" in DESCRIPTION does not seem to work any longer. I tried installing the PhenotypeSimulator package from CRAN (https://github.com/HannahVMeyer/PhenotypeSimulator), and even though it has "biocViews:" in DESCRIPTION, the Bioconductor dependency snpStats did not automatically install.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a zzz.R file to the repository.

```
.onAttach <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  if (!requireNamespace("biomaRt", quietly = TRUE)) {
    if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE)) {
      install.packages("BiocManager")
    }
    BiocManager::install("biomaRt", ask = FALSE)
    message("`biomaRt` was missing and has been installed.")
  }
}
```

Here using biomRt as an example. But that does not work. I also tried `.onLoad`.